# Two different love actions and poses

Tags: phrase-request

I was trying to search for the right phrases to describe the two actions and the two corresponding poses that are related to love and hugging. I only found: "**Jump into someone's arms**"

The first pose with the corresponding action:

[image]

The second pose with the corresponding action:

[image]

Does each of them have a name and what's the precise way to describe the action? A native speaker should see this plain and clear when reading the description.

Comment: You could probably get a description if you know someone who reads romance novels.

Comment: @user3169 I hope there are such people here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no stock "labels" for these positions but they might be *described* in iconographic terms that a native speaker would recognize:

The woman is held in the standing man's arms, *as if being carried across the threshold*.

The second one is not as easy:

The man is standing and the woman has her legs wrapped around his waist. She's looking down into his eyes, with her hands held against his cheeks. They've killed the grizzly bear that has been terrorizing them, and profess their love for one another in the driving rain. :)